# Android Actionbar ignore Colorstyle

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

i am trying to customize my Actionbar, but it will still ignore...

Maybe you can help me:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
     <item name="background">@color/primary_color</item>
</style>
```

---

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you operating with the compatibility library v7 ???????????

Comment: Sorry for late reply . Please check out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102215/action-bar-color-doesnt-change-with-appcompat-v721

Answer (score 0):

Try change styles.xml like this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color</item>
</style
```