# Action Bar color doesn't change with AppCompat v7:21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Currently I'm trying to set a custom background color to a Action Bar on AppCompat v7:21. I've tried many possibilities and until now I can't figure out what's going on.

This is my `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <color name="action_bar">#000</color>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Are you using a `Toolbar`? If so you set the background color on the view in your layout.

Comment: Unfortunately, no... :/ In fact, I've created a new project only to replicate this. If it helps, the testing device runs 4.4.4 KitKat

Comment: Have you looked into `Toolbar`? They've made quite a lot of changes in AppCompat for Material Design. Maybe it's related and you should use an older version of AppCompat if you want to keep that functionality.

Comment: Hey! Thank you. Motivated by what you said, I've done some research in Android theme codes and I found that is "not possible" to set colors individually for each view related to the look of a Material Design, so is not possible to use this code for styling the Action Bar on AppCompat v7. I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out! In fact, lot of UI things changed on API 21, and so on AppCompat v7. You can set 
Action Bar colors (among others) like this:

```
<!-- extend one of the Theme.AppCompat themes -->
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_green_A200</item>
</style>
```

Where the `color*` keys defines colors for related views, providing the visual consistency observed on Lollipop, i.e.: Is not possible (checked from my trial and error), set such colors individually when using AppCompat v7, like I was trying to do.

**Obs.**: I have tried using them, hours ago, on a `<style>` with `parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar"` which doesn't work. They must be placed within the "root" `<style>` element. It was this kind of mistake that make me write this.

Sorry for my English skills.